# How to debug IE9 JQuery AJAX caching issues?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cross-browser, kendo-ui

I have this application based on Kendo, PHP... I had troubles with erratic behavior when testing under IE9 and i was able to fix those using :

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

and by adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Now i observe many other weird behaviors like answers to Ajax request made before the current requests, etc... So looks like i still have caching issues.

OF COURSE DEAR MICROSOFT FANS... I tried the same app on firefox, Chrome and even on my own Android phone and everything works just fine !

- How to debug IE9 JQuery issues ?....
- What are the best practices when coding JQuery/Ajax applications
  considering IE's persisting disrespect of HTML standards ?

Comment: If the response should not be cached, then the server should send *real http headers* instructing the browser not to cache the response. All browsers obey real http headers - the inconsistencies occur when you don't send any http headers that specifically tell the browser how to behave. There's a decent chance IE wasn't violating any spec here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question with what we ended up doing to solve IE problems... Since we're making a Web ERP system for a specific company, they decided to force their employees to use Chrome or FireFox.
If people would massively start boycotting IE, perhaps Microsoft would stop playing with their customers and users.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used a GET parameter that holds a cache id like a timestamp to get around IE's caching issues.  Since the cache id is always different, IE interprets it as a new URL every time.

Comment: So i should do this in addition to using $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); ???? It's already adding a timestamp and the end of the GET request url.... ??

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with the $.ajaxSetup but what you're describing sounds like the same problems I was having that I fixed by generating my own cache id.

Comment: After looking at the docs for $.ajaxSetup, it looks like what I was suggesting might be unnecessary.  If you're getting responses back before the current request is made, maybe you have some issues with long running requests.  Are you running with async:false?